Definition of \sum -- how does the size selection work
When writing \[\sum\], a larger summation sign is used than when writing \(\sum\).
How does the \sum command find out which size to use?
What does \sum expand to? I am guessing it is just a shorthand for another longer series of commands, is it not?

Sum is a token defined via mathchardef, so it doesn't expand at all, it directly accesses the character from the font or the larger character in display mode

You can use \show\sum to find out what something is and whether it expands. You've tagged this plain-tex but plain doesn't use \[\] or \(\). That is LaTeX syntax. It's also not specific to the engine. Nor is it a macro, but the question is about what is believed to be a macro, so I left that one.

\[..\] uses \displaystyle, while \(...\) uses \textstyle.  (The other two are \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle.)

The \sum is big operator which has two sizes implemented in the math font. Each character or control sequence typeset in math mode has its mathcode, which includes the math class (Ord or Op or Bin or Rel...), math font family number and the slot of the font. Characters are declared by \mathcode (or \Umathcode in Unicode engines) and control sequences by \mathchardef (or \Umathchardef in Unicode engines). The \sum is declared by \mathcode in classical TeX or by \Umathchardef in Unicode math or it is defined by \def\sum{∑} in OpTeX and ∑ is declared by \Umathcode.
This means that \sum isn't a complicated macro, it is only an equivalent of a number and this number is interpreted as mathcode when it is printed. The crucial part of this mathcode is the information that its class is Op (big Operator). When TeX prints such a math character in \textstyle then it asks the direct character from the font from given slot, but when it is printed in \displaystyle then TeX asks the same font and slot, but moreover, it asks bigger variant from the font. Unicode fonts enables to have more glyphs at single slot, so this special request can be fulfilled. The classical TeX fonts have a pointer in the tfm file assigned to the given slot and this pointer points to another slot where the bigger glyph is prepared.
For example, plain TeX (i.e. classical TeX) declares \sum by:
\mathchardef\sum="1350

The first digit 1 means that it is Op (big operator) character. The third font family should be used (second digit) and 0x50 slot should be used. Plain TeX registers as third font family the cmex10 font:
\font\tenex=cmex10 % math extension
\textfont3=\tenex \scriptfont3=\tenex \scriptscriptfont3=\tenex

When you run
 tftopl cmex10 > cmex10.pl

then you can look into the metric information of the cmex10.tfm in human readable form in the cmex10.pl file. You can see, that the character O 120 (which is octal number of the slot 0x50) includes this information:
(CHARACTER O 120
   (CHARWD R 1.055559)
   (CHARDP R 1.000013)
   (NEXTLARGER O 130)
   )

The NEXTLAGRER O 130 is the pointer mentioned above. It says that the bigger glyph of the same type is at the slot octal 130, i.e. at the slot 0x58. You can run
tex testfont
Name of the font to test = cmex10
*\table\end

and you have the table of the cmex10 font in the testfont.dvi file. You can see that 0x50 slot includes smaller summation symbol and 0x58 includes its bigger variant.
When Unicode math font is used then the bigger variant has no special slot number but all alternative glyphs are at the single slot 0x2211 (Unicode summation symbol) implemented by the GSUB table.
